# spring boot data redis how to change hashmap to a Model

Tags: spring, redis, spring-boot, spring-data

I am new to spring and spring boot, and I am now using spring data redis.

1. I have a model like this

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "users")
   public class User {
       private Long id;

       @Id
       @javax.persistence.Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)

       private String email;

       @Basic
       @javax.persistence.Column(name = "email", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 128)

      //some other fields and getters and setters

   }
   ```
2. in redis, we using hash store User Model, like this.
   key is : u_id

   ```
   redis-cli> hgetall u_19999
     1) "id"
     2) "19999"
     3) "email"
     4) "xx@gmail.com"
     5) "weblink"
     6) "www.google.com"
   ```
3. in spring boot data redis

   ```
   HashOperations<String, String, String> hashOperations = this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash();
   String key = "u_"+userId;
   Map<String, String> userMap = hashOperations.entries(key);
   ```

now, userMap is a hashmap, contains the Model User's fields, now I want to change userMap to Model User

what should i do ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first got all the fields

   ```
    HashOperations<String, String, String> hashOperations =            this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForHash();
    String key = "u_"+userId;
    Map<String, String> userMap = hashOperations.entries(key);
   ```
2. using `BeanUtilsHashMapper` class

   ```
   HashMapper<User, String, String> mapper = new BeanUtilsHashMapper<User>(User.class);
   return mapper.fromHash(userMap);
   ```